# Why does ISDeploymentWizard.exe fail to launch from command line, but can be run through SSDT

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2013, ssis, sql-server-data-tools

I am trying to automate SSIS package deployment with only SSDT on my source computer. When I start the ISDeploymentWizard from SSDT for VS 2013 I can successfully deploy packages to a VM that I am running, but when I try to launch from the command line it fails with the following error:

```
To launch the Integration Services Deployment wizard, one of the Integration Services, 
Management Tools - Basic or SQL Server Data Tools has to be installed by the 
%SQL_PRODUCT_SHORT_NAME% Standard, Enterprise, Developer, or Evaluation Edition. To install
a component, run SQL Server Setup and select the component name.
```

I have SQL Server Data Tools for Visual Studio 2013 installed so I do not understand why I am receiving this error. The VM that I am running is a Windows Server 2012 R2 and has SQL 2014 installed on it. When I run the wizard from the command line on the VM it appears to work properly.

Has anyone run into the same issue? Any ideas on how to solve it?

Thanks!

edit 1: To get the package to deploy via SSDT I must launch SSDT using the "runas" command and run as the user on the VM.

Comment: What is the user account you are running this ISPac? Does that user account has sufficient access? Can you check the service account as well?

Comment: Both the source and destination users are admins

Answer (score 0):

Can you try running the command prompt as 'Run as Administrator'?

Comment: running as administrator or the user on the VM results in the same error

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by updating my SSDT through Visual Studio 2015 extensions and updates panel.